# in a webservice is the endpoint aware of domain classes or it just passes request parameters to the service class?

Tags: spring-ws

I am writing some webservices using spring. I wanna know what's the argument to the service methods: domain objects or request parameters? for example a "User" object or a bunch of strings containing name, e-mail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration (and the method signature) you will receive unmarshalled objects (Jaxb for instance), the MessageContext and so on.

Take a look in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#d5e1063), you'll find some examples and everything you need to know about the service methods and parameters.